# PhP Variables inside functions

Tags: php, function, variables

I'm having troubles with variables inside functions and being able to read them in a index.php. Let's say I have this function (functions.php):

```
function firstFunction(){
 $id = '1234';
 secondFunction($id);
}

 function secondFunction($idnumber){  
  if( $idnumber = 1234 ){
   $name = "James"; //should say "james".
 }
```

and in the index.php have something like that:

```
  include(functions.php)
<?php 
firstFunction(); 
echo $name; 
?>
```

does anyone know a possible way to do this?, i need to be a able to read from a variable inside a function that is in another function.

Also when calling a function inside a function allow this to read a variable from the first function.

Thanks.

Comment: Your PHP files contain some syntax errors. Maybe that's what's causing your problem?

Comment: it was just a draft, the thing is being able to read those variables.Thanks

Comment: `return secondFunction($id)`, `$idnumber == '1234'`, `return $name;`, `$name = firstFunction();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables created inside a function are local to it, you can't read their contents outside of it (because all function-local variables get deleted after the function finished running).

The improper way would be to make the `$name` variable global in the second function.

A better way to do it would be to use function return values: `secondFunction` returns `$name`, and `firstFunction` returns whatever it gets from calling `secondFunction($id)`.

Oh, and by the way, you have another logical error in your `secondFunction`: Your `if` test will not behave like you probably intended because you are using a variable value assignment operator (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`) which <del>always succeeds</del> returns the assigned value that evaluates to a "true" value in most (but not all) cases.

Comment: It's not that the `=`operator always succeeds, but that it returns the value that was assigned to the LHS. In this case, that's `1234`, but it could be a value like `false` or `0`, in which case the `if` condition would fail.

Comment: +1 good explanation: however, its too bad that you didn't explain the "scope" notion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a variable like that it is out of scope what you need to do is as follows

```
function firstFunction(){
    $id = '1234';
    return secondFunction($id);
}

function secondFunction($idnumber){  
    if( $idnumber == 1234 ){
       return "James";
    }
}
```

Then in your index do this

```
<?php 
    include(functions.php);
    echo firstFunction(); 
?>
```

A variable that is out of scope can not be accessed for example if you defined a variable inside a if statement is would only be able to be used in that statement and it is the same with the functions and variables that are inside. Thought I needed to explain my answer more.

Comment: `include(functions.php)` will slap you with syntax errors: Missing semicolon, missing quotes around the file name.

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad practice - using globals. The answer you need is:

```
global $name;
```

You need to put it above the row:

```
$name = "James"; //should say "james".
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare $name inside second function, so it only exists there (that is it's "Scope").
To use it's value you need the functions to return it:

```
function secondFunction($idnumber){  
    if ( $idnumber == 1234 ){
        $name = "James"; //should say "james".
    }
    else {
        $name = "";
    }
    return $name;
}

function firstFunction(){
    $id = 1234;
    return secondFunction($id);
}
```

and in the index.php have something like that:

```
<?php
    include 'functions.php';
    $name = firstFunction(); 
    echo $name; 
?>
```

Comment: You still have syntactical and logical errors in that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

## index.php

```
<?php 
// Includes
include("functions.php");

// Create a variable to store the output of your function
$returned_name = firstFunction(); 

// Echo the variable
echo "Name: " . $returned_name;
?>
```

## functions.php

```
<?php
// Function 1
function firstFunction() {
    $id = "1234";
    return secondFunction($id);
}

// Function 2
function secondFunction($idnumber) {  
    if ($idnumber == "1234") {
        $name = "James";
    } else if ($idnumber == "5678") {
        $name = "Brian";
    }

    return $name;
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what your ultimate goal is but the shortest way to do this is to forget firstFunction and in your index just write... **echo secondFunction("1234");**